# how to use replaceWhere option with Apache iceberg while writing data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

I'm currently trying to write data using Iceberg to an external Hive table which is partitioned by `partition_date` column.

Before writing the data with Iceberg format, `test` table has 2 rows,

```
("2015-01-02", "S01233", "3-goods-purchased")
("2015-01-02", "S01234", "4-goods-purchased")
```

After writing data as below
Code:

```
val input = Seq(("2015-01-02", "S01233", "5-goods-purchased"))
.toDF("partition_date", "order_id", "goods_purchased")

input.write
.format("iceberg")
.partitionBy("partition_date")
.option("path","s3://some-bucket-path/test")
.option(
"replaceWhere",
s"order_id in ('S01233')")
.mode("overwrite")
.saveAsTable("default.test")
```

Table `test` gets overwritten and only one row is shown in the output.

```
("2015-01-02", "S01233", "5-goods-purchased")
```

What I expected is this,

```
("2015-01-02", "S01233", "5-goods-purchased")
("2015-01-02", "S01234", "4-goods-purchased")
```

`replaceWhere` option provided as part of write statement, doesn't seem to work as expected.

Is there anything I'm missing? or does Iceberg support `replaceWhere` option which is working with `delta` format.?

Comment: Have you tried replaceWhere while reading or on the input dataframe instead on the writer?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy As far as I understand, replaceWhere is like a filter. To answer your question, I'm not reading anything here. I have a input dataframe, all I'm doing is just writing to Iceberg table, but with an option of `replaceWhere` which you can see in my code snippet.

Comment: for delta it is mentioned that you should not be using it with writer-overwrite as per DELTA_REPLACE_WHERE_IN_OVERWRITE in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/error-messages/ and not sure for Iceberg

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, iceberg does not have this at present. You can use the following alternatives:
`data.writeTo("prod.db.table").overwrite(functions.col("order_id").isin("S01233"))`